# I defined Check touching (if player touches object) and got this error: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I copied an example from my teacher and run into following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/LF15/Python/29.09.20 TEST.py", line 81, in <module>
    checkTouching()
  File "G:/LF15/Python/29.09.20 TEST.py", line 45, in checkTouching
    if -10 < y - ballY < 10 and -10 < x - ballX < 10:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

here's my code:

```
import random
import pygame
pygame.init()

#Farben bestimmen
red = pygame.color.Color("#FF8080")
blue = pygame.color.Color("#8080FF")
white = pygame.color.Color("#FFFFFF")
black = pygame.color.Color("#000000")

width = 400
height = 300
windowsize = [width, height]
window = pygame.display.set_mode(windowsize)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Position Spieler
x = int(windowsize[0]/2)
y = int (windowsize[1]/2)

#Position Ball

ballX = random.randrange(0, windowsize[0])
ballY = random.randrange(0, windowsize[1])

def checkOffWindowX(x) :
    if x > windowsize[0]:
        x = 0
    elif x < 0:
        x = windowsize[0]
        return x

def checkOffWindowY(y):
    if y > windowsize[1]:
        y = 0
    elif y < 0:
        y = windowsize[1]
        return y

def checkTouching():
    global x
    global ballX
    global y
    global ballY
    if -10 < y - ballY < 10 and -10 < x - ballX < 10:
        pygame.draw.circle (window, white, [x, y],15)
        xDiff = x - ballX
        yDiff = y - ballY
        #Falls der Spielball in einer Ecke sein sollte
        if  ballY == 0:
            xDiff -= 5
        elif ballX == windowsize[0]:
            xDiff += 5
        if ballY == windowsize[1]:
            yDiff += 5
        #Spielball und Spieler verschieben
            x += xDiff *3
            ballX -= xDiff *3
            y += xDiff *3
            ballY -= yDiff *3

done = False
while not done:
    window.fill(black)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #Bewegung Spieler
    if keys [pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += 1
    #Positionsbestimmung
    x = checkOffWindowX(x)
    y = checkOffWindowY(y)
    ballX = checkOffWindowX(ballX)
    ballY = checkOffWindowY(ballY)
    #Auf Berührung testen
    checkTouching()
    #Spieler zeichnen
    pygame.draw.circle (window, red, [x, y], 6)
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    clock.tick(72)
pygame.quit()
```

The funktion where the error is about checking if the player touches the object. BTW ignore the German comments. If you want to know what is written in the comments, I can translate it. I'm new to pygame and I'm still learning the basic functions

Comment: Think carefully about the logic in `def checkOffWindowX(x)` and `def checkOffWindowY(Y)`. Also, make sure you understand what happens if the end of a function is reached without a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). `checkOffWindowX` and `checkOffWindowY` need to return a value in any cases. If the functions don't explicitly return a value, the return value is `None` and thus `x`, `y`, `ballX` respectively `ballY` becomes `None`:

```py
def checkOffWindowX(x) :
    if x > windowsize[0]:
        x = 0
    elif x < 0:
        x = windowsize[0]

    #<--| INDENTATION
    return x

def checkOffWindowY(y):
    if y > windowsize[1]:
        y = 0
    elif y < 0:
        y = windowsize[1]

    #<--| INDENTATION
    return y
```

---

You can simplify the code by using the `%` (modulo) operator:

```py
def checkOffWindowX(x) :
    return x % windowsize[0]

def checkOffWindowY(y):
    return y % windowsize[1]
```

Comment: the % modulo operator worked, but I don't understand what it does. Can you explain it to me ? I fixed the indentation and it worked, thanks.

Comment: @Tinko The (`%`) modulo operator calculates the remainder of a division as in any other programming language. e.g.: 7 // 2 = 3 and 7 % 2 = 1, because 2 * 3 + 1 = 7.  See [Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)). 7 is the divided, 2 is the divisor, 3 is the quotient and 1 is the remainder.